# Converting big endian bytes into integer?

Tags: python, c#, endianness

I have this python code:

```py
f = open('file.bin', 'rb')
b = f.read(2)
bytes = b[0x0:0x2] //this is b'\x10\x24', for example
f.close()
a = int.from_bytes(bytes, 'big') //returns 4132
```

I can't seem to figure out how to achieve the same thing in C#.

Did find this method:

```cs
public static int IntFromBigEndianBytes(byte[] data, int startIndex = 0)
    {
      return (data[startIndex] << 24) | (data[startIndex + 1] << 16) | (data[startIndex + 2] << 8) | data[startIndex + 3];
    }
```

Trying that method always results in an IndexOutOfRangeException because my input bytes are less than 4. An insight to why this is happening, or otherwise any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding any other problem. There are many ways to do this, essentially what you are asking is how to take a byte array that represent a *16 bit* value (`short`,`Int16`) and assign it to an `int`

**Given**

```
public static int IntFromBigEndianBytes(byte[] data) 
    => (data[0] << 8) | data[1];

public static int IntFromBigEndianBytes2(byte[] data) 
    => BitConverter.ToInt16(data.Reverse().ToArray());
```

**Usage**

```
var someArray = new byte[]{0x10, 0x24};

Console.WriteLine(IntFromBigEndianBytes(someArray));
Console.WriteLine(IntFromBigEndianBytes2(someArray));
```

**Output**

```
4132
4132
```

[**Full Demo Here**](http://%20%20%20https://dotnetfiddle.net/V6ln0E)

<sub>***Note** you should also be using `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == false` to determine the endianness of your system with these methods, and reverse the logic on a big endian architecture*</sub>

Comment: This is great, thank you.

However, `Convert.ToInt32(array.Hex()), 16);` also did the trick, where `.Hex()` turns the bytes into a hex string.